# Chrome workspace encoding

Tags: google-chrome, encoding, developer-tools

I have enabled workspace in chrome developer toools. When I save javascript file(*.js), it has ANSI encoding - before it was UTF-8. How can i set that when I save file in developer tools, that file keep original encoding?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but instead my file was encoded as ISO-8859-1 and Chrome developer tools seems to save it as UTF-8. I've just filed a bug for this at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596037

Comment: Added steps to reproduce this bug to the comment
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596037#c7

Comment: One file in the workspace was UTF-8 BOM and chrome saved it as ASCII. Most other files in the workspace are ASCII encoded so perhaps chrome thought they should all be the same.

Comment: Relative github discussion: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/devtools-docs/issues/30#issuecomment-61744476